# Python Reverse words performance

Tags: python, string, performance

I was trying to reverse words in Python. Simple problem (leetcode).

**Solution 1**: *(20 ms - 99.54% percentile)*

```
words = reversed([word.strip() for word in words if word != ''])

answer = " ".join(words).strip()
```

**Solution 2**: *(24 ms - 48% percentile)*

```
words = [word.strip() for word in words if word != '']

answer = " ".join(reversed(words)).strip()
```

I am trying to find the reasoning for this variance?

Comment: How often did you run each solution?

Comment: can you provide expected input and output

Comment: what are the "percentile" values and where are they coming from, something to do with placement in leetcode?  as others have said it'll just be normal variance due to e.g. thread scheduling, GC, background jobs exerting RAM/cache pressure, CPU throttling…

Comment: Sample Input: ' a b c '
Sample Output: 'c b a'

Percentiles are coming when leet code runs this code multiple times and calculates the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Run a benchmark using `timeit` (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html) to see that the time is more or less the same (for my guessed input sample):

```
def opt1(words):
  words = reversed([word.strip() for word in words if word != ''])
  answer = " ".join(words).strip()
  return answer

def opt2(words):
  words = [word.strip() for word in words if word != '']
  answer = " ".join(reversed(words)).strip()
  return answer

import timeit, functools

t_opt1 = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(opt1, words))
t_opt2 = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(opt2, words))
# run 5000 times each method:
print('opt1: ', t_opt1.timeit(5000))
print('opt2: ', t_opt2.timeit(5000))
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference here is in when references to the temporary `list` are discarded (during `join` in the first case, not until function exit in the second case). But that's unlikely to matter unless the timing framework is broken in some way (it should incorporate any clean up times in both cases).

Otherwise, barring some alternate interpreter with weird behaviors being involved, both sets of code should behave identically (the op codes are identical, aside from swapping the order depending on whether the `list` is stored first or `reversed` is called first); timing differences seem more likely to be random than anything else.